# [error]Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: '3.1.0'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have a release Pipeline in which I use Azure PowerShell to deploy artifacts into AppServices in Azure.
It was working fine around two weeks ago but now failing.
I stayed nights troubleshooting and searching around for solution, but no success :(

In the *Preferred Azure Powershell Version* I have this tip: "

> In case of hosted agents, the supported Azure PowerShell Version is:
> 1.0.0, 1.6.0, 2.3.2, 2.6.0, 3.1.0 (Hosted VS2017 Queue). To pick the latest version available on the agent, select "Latest installed
> version".

"

I installed Az version 3.1.0 with the below command from normal Powershell using Pipeline on the target agent:

```
Install-Module -Name Az  -Scope CurrentUser -RequiredVersion 3.1.0  -AllowClobber -Repository PSGallery -Force -SkipPublisherCheck
```

I can see Az module 3.1.0 installed successfully when I run Get-InstalledModule.

I tried both Tasks version 4 and 5 that supports Az and tried different versions from supported versions and all are failing with the error "Az.Accounts module not found".

I also tried installing latest version of Az but also failed with the same error.

We are using Hosted agents.

I dont know what is wrong and why VS2017 is showing lower supported versions?

Please help!

I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: But you can manually find it using `Get-Module`?

Comment: I dont have direct access to the agent machines, I use Pipelines to execute my commands. When I ran `Get-Module` I dont see Az module in the list. What does this mean?

Comment: You could try Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion 2.2.3 if it is not already available.

Comment: I can see Az.Accounts version 2.7.2 is listed with `Get-InstalledModule` .. if you see the previous comment 'Get-Module' does not show any Az module which is weird!  I'm trying to find out the reason .. you have any clue? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you imported module after installing? `Import-Module Az`

Comment: Actually I didnt try to import the module in the standard PowerShell task because I test Azure PowerShell task if it loads or not .. and it doesnt load with the error in the title ... meanwhile, I'm testing  Import-Module Az and I think it will fails to load

Comment: I just tried Import-Module in PowerShell task and it failed with the below error:

2022-02-23T10:19:42.1740906Z Import-Module : The specified module 'Az' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module 
2022-02-23T10:19:42.1745134Z directory.
2022-02-23T10:19:42.1746679Z At E:\ado\9203-1\_work\_temp\db57321c-2c20-41d1-af08-b80d55ccb8d8.ps1:5 char:1
2022-02-23T10:19:42.1747121Z + Import-Module Az

Comment: I added different paths to the PATH env variable
`C:\Users\svcTFSProd1Admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az\3.1.0;C:\Users\svcTFSProd1Admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Users\svcTFSProd1Admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az`
But it still fails to import the module.

Comment: Update:
I found out that the env variable `PSModulePath` does not include the path where the Az module is installed `C:\Users\svcTFSProd1Admin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` 
I appended it in the code and Az.Accounts loaded successfully!
BUT Azure PowerShell is still failing because the path is missing the correct one.
How to fix this? considering that I done have access to the agent machines

Comment: @MoSayed have you managed to solve the issue? I have the same problem